# Error while performing LULC classification

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I get this error while performing LULC classification:

> Error: "FeatureCollection (Error)  Image.select: Pattern 'SR_B1' did
> not match any bands.

Script code:

```
var image= ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
             .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-02-01', '2020-03-31'))
             .filterBounds(geometry)
             .map(function(image){return image.clip(shape)});
print('LANDSAT 8 IMAGE FOR 2018',image);

//ADD IMAGE ON MAP
Map.addLayer(image);

//TO KNOW LIST OF ELEMENTS
print(image.first().bandNames());

//MOSAICING
var medianpixels= image.median();
var medianpixelssclipped= medianpixels.clip(shape).divide(10000); 
print("MOSAIC LAYER FOR REGION", medianpixels);
Map.addLayer(medianpixels,{bands: ['SR_B5', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B3'],min:0, max: 50000}, 'MOSAIC LAYER');

//FOR CLASSIFICATION
var filtered= image.filter(ee.Filter.eq('image',90));

//MERGE FUNCTION
var classes=water.merge(riverbed).merge(settlement).merge(mangrove).merge(forest).merge(agriculture).merge(fallowland);
print(classes,'Merge');

var bands=['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B7'];
var training= image.toBands().select(bands).sampleRegions
({
  collection: classes,
  properties: ['landuse'],
  scale: 30
});
print(training);

//CLASSIFIER FUNCTION(.smileCart)
var classifier= ee.Classifier.smileCart().train
({features:training,
  classProperty:'landuse',
  inputProperties:bands});
  
//RUN THE CLASSIFICATION
var classified=image.toBands().select(bands).classify(classifier);

//DISPLAY THE CLASSIFICATION
Map.centerObject(classes,9);
Map.addLayer(classified,{min:0,max:7,palette:['#0f07d6','#00FFFF','#b09f89','#c40000','#3e8d27','#98ff00','#bc814a']},
'Classification for East Godavari 2020');
```

Script Link: https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/112cc983f19fb247d22a7aedcb6baf2b

Answer (score 1):

`image.toBands()` is converting each band in each images of the image collection to an individual band. It is creating 665 band out of 35 images with 19 bands each. Something like this:
[image]

Instead of using that use `medianpixelssclipped` as you have already mosaic and clipped your data.

```
//MERGE FUNCTION
var classes=water.merge(riverbed).merge(settlement).merge(mangrove).merge(forest).merge(agriculture).merge(fallowland);
print(classes,'Merge');

var bands=['SR_B1','SR_B2','SR_B3','SR_B4','SR_B5','SR_B6','SR_B7'];
var training= medianpixelssclipped.select(bands).sampleRegions
({
  collection: classes,
  properties: ['landuse'],
  scale: 30
});
print(training);

//CLASSIFIER FUNCTION(.smileCart)
var classifier= ee.Classifier.smileCart().train
({features:training,
  classProperty:'landuse',
  inputProperties:bands});

//RUN THE CLASSIFICATION
var classified=medianpixelssclipped.select(bands).classify(classifier);
```

Comment: Thankyou Saumyata for your suggestion, but I am still unable to correct it.  Can you please write the correct code for my reference. In advance,Thankyou so much for your suggestion and time.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Thankyou so much Saumyata. It is working now.